# Show ListView item only after download the image using Picasso

Tags: android, listview, picasso

I am using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load images in my ListView. The items of this ListView does not have a placeholder image, and the images loaded have different sizes. This list works as a timeline in my app. My issue is when I do a quickly scroll, the items appear and after a little time the image is showed. This causes the unwanted effect the items are expanded as I scroll the list.

**I want to know if there is some way to show this item only after Picasso has downloaded the image.**

This is how I set the image in the getView of my adpater:

```
View v = convertView;

ViewHolder viewHolder;

if (v == null) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timeline_item, parent, false);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.photo = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    v.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    ViewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
}

Picasso.with(context).load(timeline.getImage()).into(ViewHolder.photo);
return v;
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are loading the images?

Comment: i am not sure if you can skip item which doesnt have image and come back to add it later. Why dont you put some default image or progressBar until image is loaded, and change that to image when it is ready

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with a relatively similar issue before.  What you are looking for is a callback method.  Picasso has such a thing when you are creating your request.

```
public void into(android.widget.ImageView target, Callback callback)
```

So you need to add an implementation of com.squareup.picasso.Callback to your current code and provide it here:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(timeline.getImage()).into(ViewHolder.photo, <Callback here>);
```

In that callback you add the image to the listview.

Of course there is a problem with this.  The code snippet appears to be from the getView() of your adapter.  This means that you are trying to only add the view to the ListView, after you've scrolled to that view in the ListView.

I do have a suggestion of how you can achieve this, but I'm not 100% sure how well it will work.  You could try having the layout (R.layout.timeline_item) set to visibility View.GONE.  This may cause all of the images to start loading at the same time as soon the ListView is loaded, and I'm assuming you want them to only start loading once they're reached in the list.

Comment: I saw this callback, but I don't know how to use it to resolve my issue. Because I will know when the image has succesfully downloaded, but the list has already scrolled and the list item without image already will be appearing in the list, and finally after Picasso download the image, this item is expanded, causing the side effect I have now.

Comment: I'm not sure you quite got what I meant when I said to have the layout set to visibility View.GONE.  That's the whole item not just the view.  As I stated before, I'm not sure how well that solution will work toward your goal, but your comment seems to indicate you didn't quite get what I meant by that.

However, If you don't want to see any loading whatsoever, your only option is to preload the images that you'll be using.  You can use the fetch method for that purpose. That way when you use the into method later on, your image is already cached.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with Picasso all is possible :)

I don't really know that you want to do but I guess that the solution is put something while image is loading, isn't it?

you can use that

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
.error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
.into(imageView);
```

You can set up an image while it's loading and in case of error, show an icon for error,just saying.

If this is not valid for you, let me know and we can try and find another solution.

Comment: The problem is: the images I load have different sizes (same width, but different heights). So, if I show a placeholder when downloading the same effect will occcurs, that is the expansion or  reduction of the image showed in my ListView as I make scroll.

Comment: aham, ok, I know, in this case you can use other parameters like width a height to each img. So, this way, all your photos will get the same size, and then, you can centercrop to center the img... better with a example:

Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)

Comment: Yes, it is a possible solution, but I have to show the images they way they are, that is, with different heights.

Comment: Ok, So I don't understand you want to do, because you don't want change the size and you don't want to put a placeholder while is loading... What do you do? Do you want to when you do scroll, there isn't lag??

Comment: The problem is not what I "want" to do. The problem is what I "have" to do. Again, I can't add a fix height to the images, so put a placeholder will not resolve the issue. And yes, there is a tag. I set it to my ViewHolder.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, sorry men. try this, create a thread inside of getView() and throw from this the picasso callback. This way, you will not have lag. Tell me something when you try this